# I need help finding the best set of cards in a card game from a 500 card database

Tags: game-development, playing-cards

Let's say there is a 1vs1 card game where my opponent and I choose 5 cards from a database of
400-500 cards (each of us 5 cards) and based on some rules, we play until one of us wins.

I want to build a code to give me the best set of cards from this database to have the highest chance of winning against my opponent.

I don't know much about programming and I want to start learning. I created this question here to get a roadmap. Which programming language do you suggest?

Comment: That's quite a complicated question, going already deep into optimization algorithms. It's a very interesting field, but maybe postpone this question for later, and start by building the basic game mechanics. If you are content with a simple text interface, i would suggest maybe Python as an entry language. But this is very subjective, and everybody here will recommend sth different :D

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've been told that I should use machine learning to find the best set of card. Is it the right path to start building the mechanics of the game with let's say python (as you mentioned) and then use machine learning to find the set with the highest win rate by letting all the possible sets of cards fight each other. Am I even make sense?

Comment: that is one way yes. depending on your rules/game mechanics it could be the only way. 
machine learning is a whole other topic, but if you want to go this way, absolutely use python. look into https://scikit-learn.org/stable/ to start. 
but as i said, take baby steps: learn some basic python, learn programming some game mechanis - in parallel you can learn some basics of ML with scikit (there are tons of good tutorials, youtube channels etc. but let me recommend a fantastic book: Hands-On Machine Learning with Scikit-Learn and TensorFlow by Aurélien Géron

Comment: "I have a screwdriver and a hammer, don't know much about tools yet. How to I build a three-story colonial-style house?"  Maybe you should start with a bookshelf.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

this depends on the card rules etc. do you know the cards from your opponent before they are all played?

(should be a comment, but i need 50Karma for that)

Comment: No, I won't be able to see which cards he/she will choose until the game starts. When the game starts, both sets will be shown and based on some rules, the cards fight with each other until one player wins. I've been told that I should use machine learning to consider all the possible sets and find the set with the highest win rate. Is it possible? Can I have more detail about this solution?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).